# Duplicate class issue with Android App: Room DB

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio, android-room

I have started with the Android Studio, Hello World "Navigation Drawer Views Activity". I am modifying it and I am now trying to add Room DB support. This introduces a Duplicate class issue between `org.jetbrains:annotatins:23.0.0 and com.intellij:annotations:13.X`

I got around the compile/run issue by excluding the duplicate class from the Room dependency like so

```
kapt {
    "implementation"("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"){
        exclude(group = "com.intellij", module = "annotations")
    }
}
```

However, this means (as expected!) that when I try and instantiate a new DB instance I get a `RuntimeException`, I assume because I've just excluded the `com.intellij:annotations` module that has the class I need

```
if (INSTANCE == null) {
                try {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    AppDatabase.class, "app_database")
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }catch(Exception e){
```

Results in

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.demo.gametime.dao.AppDatabase. AppDatabase_Impl does not exist
    2024-01-31 11:47:07.634  6124-6124  System.err              com.demo.gametime                   W    at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
    2024-01-31 11:47:07.634  6124-6124  System.err              com.demo.gametime                   W    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1351)
    2024-01-31 11:47:07.635  6124-6124  System.err              com.demo.gametime                   W    at com.demo.gametime.dao.AppDatabase.getDatabase(AppDatabase.java:28)
```

My question is, how do I get around the Duplicate Class issue without breaking the functionality of RoomDB?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by specifying annotation processor and ,commented out kapt like below, but I have no idea of the implications of what I have done!!. Anyone able to explain? Is there any disadvantage to commenting out kapt and specifying annotation processor directly as I have done? Is this a valid solution or a work around?

```
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.1") // Use the latest version
implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1")
// i added annotationProcessor here
val room_version = "2.6.1"
annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")


implementation("org.jetbrains:annotations:23.0.0")

//I commented out this
```

//    kapt {
//        "implementation"("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1"){
//            exclude(group = "com.intellij", module = "annotations")
//        }
//    }